# (Derivative measurability)

Tags: measure-theory

**Exercise** *(Derivative measurability).*

Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: I \to\mathbb{R}$ a derivable application on $I.$ We extend $f$ to $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R} $  by laying $\tilde{f} (x) = 0$ if $x\notin I$. We define $f_k(x) = 2^k (\tilde{f}(x+2^{-k})-\tilde{f}(x))$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$.

Show that the functions $f_k$ are measurable, and deduce that $f{'}: I \to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable

Hint: (we can assume that $I$ is open).

**my problem:** why we can assume that $I$ is open?

if $I$ is not open, can we say that $\tilde{f}$ is derivable application on $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is a closed interval, say $[a,b]$ then, at the end points $f'$ denotes the one sided derivatives. The inverse image under $f'$ of any Borel set is the same as the inverse image under $f'$ restricted to $(a,b)$ except for some subset of $\{a,b\}$ . If you remove  a finite set from a Borel set you still get a Borl lset. Hence, we may suppose that $I$ is an open interval.

Similar argument holds when the interval is half-closed.

Comment: But can I work on any interval $I$ without specifying its nature?

Comment: If the interval has  an end point you have to consider one-sided derivative at that point. Excpet for thsi ther si no difference. @saidnani